# Complex numbers Argand diagrams

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm confused on a question I just come across, I' only recently started working with complex numbers and do not know how to go about answering these questions :

(a) Give in an Argand diagram a geometric description of all complex numbers z such that $ \bar z $= $z^{-1}$

(b) Express the reflection across the line Re(z)=Im(z), the diagonal of the Argand diagram, as an operation with complex numbers, combining multiplication and conjugation. Hint: you know that complex conjugation is just reflection about the real axis in the Argand diagram. Try to find a way to rotate the Re(z)=Im(z) diagonal onto the real axis to perform a reflection, then rotate back.

Comment: What exaclty are you stuck on? Part (a), for example, is just a matter of putting a set into Argand diagram form. Do you know the definitions of all the terms involved?

Comment: That's the thing, I dont't. I only recently started learning about this and im just not sure on how to implement certain theories, nor do I know which theories apply to what

Comment: Well, then the first step is to read the definitions.

Comment: what are the definitions? can you recommend me a webpage to look at? ill delete this question as it seems i havent researched enough

Comment: Why are you asking me? You clearly got these questions for somewhere; that source should also have the relevant defintions. If not, check Wikipedia, etc.

Comment: They are from a problem sheet, they do not have the definitions on them. I am asking you since you seem to know that I should start by looking at the definitions, and this being a place to ask questions I asked if you knew where I could get them from. Thank you for your help, no matter how useless it was. I'll be sure to think twice before posting again if this is the type of 'help' I will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**:

a) $\bar z=z^{-1}$ is equivalent to $z\bar z=1$, i.e. $|z|^2=1\iff |z|=1$.

b) A rotation which moves a point on the diagonal of the Argand plane onto the real axis corresponds to multiplication by $\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{i\pi}4}$. So you have to take the conjugate of $z\mkern1.5mu \mathrm e^{-\frac{i\pi}4}$, then perform the reverse rotation, i.e. multiply by $\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}4}$.

Comment: I think my answer is similar, I got it after a while. Thanks!

Comment: Great minds think (almost) together ;o)